# How to implement auto scroll vertically on Jquery Sortable Plugin?

Tags: jquery, sortables

I'm using Jquery-Sortable [plugin](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable) as in here to build my menu project drap & drop just wordpress menubuilder.

Container height containing all menu items is fixed so that as the number of menu items exceed the container height, it is hard to drag the top item one to the bottom of container.

```js
$(function() {
  $("ol.default").sortable({
    group: 'item'
  });
})
```

```css
body.dragging,
body.dragging * {
  cursor: move !important;
}

.overflow {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.dragged {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2000;
}


/* line 10, jquery-sortable.css.sass */

ol.vertical {
  margin: 0 0 9px 0;
}


/* line 12, jquery-sortable.css.sass */

ol.vertical li {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  color: #0088cc;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

ol.vertical li.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

ol.vertical li.placeholder:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  top: -4px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: red;
  border-right: none;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol i.icon-move {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ol li.highlight {
  background: #333333;
  color: #999999;
}

ol li.highlight i.icon-move {
  background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
}

ol.nested_with_switch,
ol.nested_with_switch ol {
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

ol.nested_with_switch.active,
ol.nested_with_switch ol.active {
  border: 1px solid #333333;
}

ol.nested_with_switch li,
ol.simple_with_animation li,
ol.default li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>


<div class="overflow">
  <ol class="default vertical">
    <li>elem1</li>
    <li>elem2</li>
    <li>elem3</li>
    <li>elem4</li>
    <li>elem5</li>
    <li>elem6</li>
    <li>elem7</li>
    <li>elem8</li>
    <li>elem9</li>
    <li>elem10</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="overflow">
  <ol class="default vertical">
    <li>elem1</li>
    <li>elem2</li>
    <li>elem3</li>
    <li>elem4</li>
    <li>elem5</li>
    <li>elem6</li>
    <li>elem7</li>
    <li>elem8</li>
    <li>elem9</li>
    <li>elem10</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I tried to search around for auto scroll solution but seem there was not much mentioned about this issue, while plugin github mentioned [this issue](https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable/issues/237) but seemed it did not work for my case.

How could I fixed this? Please kindly help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use correct version of jQuery UI, try the snippet below

```js
$("ol.default").sortable({
  onDrag: (item, position, sup, event) => {
    const container = $(item).parents('.overflow');
    const containerTop = container.offset().top;
    const containerBottom = containerTop + container.height();

    if (event.pageY > containerBottom) {
      container.scrollTop(container.scrollTop() + 10);
    } else if (event.pageY < containerTop) {
      container.scrollTop(container.scrollTop() - 10);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body.dragging,
body.dragging * {
  cursor: move !important;
}

.overflow {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.dragged {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 2000;
}


/* line 10, jquery-sortable.css.sass */

ol.vertical {
  margin: 0 0 9px 0;
}


/* line 12, jquery-sortable.css.sass */

ol.vertical li {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  color: #0088cc;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

ol.vertical li.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

ol.vertical li.placeholder:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  top: -4px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: red;
  border-right: none;
}

ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol i.icon-move {
  cursor: pointer;
}

ol li.highlight {
  background: #333333;
  color: #999999;
}

ol li.highlight i.icon-move {
  background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
}

ol.nested_with_switch,
ol.nested_with_switch ol {
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

ol.nested_with_switch.active,
ol.nested_with_switch ol.active {
  border: 1px solid #333333;
}

ol.nested_with_switch li,
ol.simple_with_animation li,
ol.default li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>


<div class="overflow">
  <ol class="default vertical">
    <li>elem1</li>
    <li>elem2</li>
    <li>elem3</li>
    <li>elem4</li>
    <li>elem5</li>
    <li>elem6</li>
    <li>elem7</li>
    <li>elem8</li>
    <li>elem9</li>
    <li>elem10</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="overflow">
  <ol class="default vertical">
    <li>elem1</li>
    <li>elem2</li>
    <li>elem3</li>
    <li>elem4</li>
    <li>elem5</li>
    <li>elem6</li>
    <li>elem7</li>
    <li>elem8</li>
    <li>elem9</li>
    <li>elem10</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. It works for jquery-ui, however my current project has all adapted with jquery sortable library of this one https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/ already. I could not change my current project to adapt with jquery-ui widget because it a lot of work to change. Thanks

Comment: now try it, I've updated the snippet to use the previous library

Comment: it's ok for now that scrollbar follows mouse while dragging but a dragged item one does not always follows when I moved it to a very top or bottom. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, that functionality is not possible without changing the code inside the library, because this library does not provide any method to reset the pointer manually.

Comment: quoted from author "You should be able to get your desired behavior without hacking the source." https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable/issues/46

Comment: it does not help either

Answer (score 0):

**style.css**

```
body.dragging,
            body.dragging * {
              cursor: move !important;
            }

            .overflow {
              height: 200px;
              overflow-x: hidden;
              overflow-y: auto;
              margin-top: 20px;
            }

            .dragged {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              opacity: 0.5;
              z-index: 2000;
            }


            /* line 10, jquery-sortable.css.sass */

            ol.vertical {
              margin: 0 0 9px 0;
            }


            /* line 12, jquery-sortable.css.sass */

            ol.vertical li {
              display: block;
              margin: 5px;
              padding: 5px;
              border: 1px solid #cccccc;
              color: #0088cc;
              background: #eeeeee;
            }

            ol.vertical li.placeholder {
              position: relative;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              border: none;
            }

            ol.vertical li.placeholder:before {
              position: absolute;
              content: "";
              width: 0;
              height: 0;
              margin-top: -5px;
              left: -5px;
              top: -4px;
              border: 5px solid transparent;
              border-left-color: red;
              border-right: none;
            }

            ol {
              list-style-type: none;
            }

            ol i.icon-move {
              cursor: pointer;
            }

            ol li.highlight {
              background: #333333;
              color: #999999;
            }

            ol li.highlight i.icon-move {
              background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
            }

            ol.nested_with_switch,
            ol.nested_with_switch ol {
              border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
            }

            ol.nested_with_switch.active,
            ol.nested_with_switch ol.active {
              border: 1px solid #333333;
            }

            ol.nested_with_switch li,
            ol.simple_with_animation li,
            ol.default li {
              cursor: pointer;
            }
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vertical Scroll in jquery vertical short</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <script>
            (function(){
                $(function(){
                   $(function() {
                       window.posY = 0;
                       window.posX = 0;
                       window.dragStart = false;
                       window.dragCon_el = null;
                       window.dragCon_left = 0;
                       window.dragCon_top = 0;
                      $("ol.default").sortable({
                          pullPlaceholder: false,
                          vertical: true,
                          group: 'item',
                          onDrag: function($item, position, _super, event) {
                              if (window.dragStart && position.top >= window.dragCon_el.get(0).scrollTop + window.dragCon_el.height() + window.dragCon_top) {
                                      window.dragCon_el.get(0).scrollTo(
                                          window.dragCon_el.get(0).scrollLeft + ((position.left - posX) - (window.dragCon_left * 2)),
                                          window.dragCon_el.get(0).scrollTop + ((position.top - posY) - (window.dragCon_top * 2))
                                      );
                                   window.posX = event.pageX;
                                   window.posY = event.pageY;
                               }
                          },
                          onDragStart: function($item, container, _super, event) {
                              let $container = $item.closest('.overflow');
                              window.dragStart = true;
                              window.posY = event.pageY;
                              window.posX = event.pageX;
                              window.dragCon_el = $container;
                              window.dragCon_top = $container.offset().top;
                              window.dragCon_left = $container.offset().left;
                          },
                          onDrop: function($item, container, _super, event) {
                              window.dragStart = false;
                          }
                      });
                    }); 
                });
            })(jQuery)
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="overflow">
          <ol class="default vertical">
            <li>elem1</li>
            <li>elem2</li>
            <li>elem3</li>
            <li>elem4</li>
            <li>elem5</li>
            <li>elem6</li>
            <li>elem7</li>
            <li>elem8</li>
            <li>elem9</li>
            <li>elem10</li>
          </ol>
        </div>

        <div class="overflow">
          <ol class="default vertical">
            <li>elem1</li>
            <li>elem2</li>
            <li>elem3</li>
            <li>elem4</li>
            <li>elem5</li>
            <li>elem6</li>
            <li>elem7</li>
            <li>elem8</li>
            <li>elem9</li>
            <li>elem10</li>
          </ol>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tested and it does not work smoothly, and I dragged and move item to bottom of container, it the scrollbar was running back to the top. Thanks

Comment: It also does not work when I dragged and move item to top. Thanks